# Solving the polynominal: $s(t) = -16t^2 + 48t + 160$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, rational-functions

The height of a ball is thrown directly upward from an initial height of $160$ ft with an initial velocity of $48$ ft per second is given by the function:

$s(t) = -16t^2 + 48t + 160$, where $s(t)$ gives the ball's height above ground in feet, $t$ seconds after it is thrown. How long will it take for the ball to hit the ground?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I need help in trying to solve it. I do not know where to start. Do I start by factoring it out?

Comment: Divide it all by 16, and try to factorise it then. It comes out nicely.

Comment: When the ball hits the ground $s(t)=0$. How do you solve such kind of equations?

Comment: So it becomes s(t) = -t^2 + 3t + 10

Comment: yep, and factorise that to get...

Comment: @HassanMuhammad s(t) = 0, you would just plug the 0 in for the t's. correct?

Comment: @thes4s If you put in 0's you won't get 0 on the right side. You need to find values _which_ will give you zero on the right side. You have to _factorize_ it.

Comment: @thes4s Noooooooooooooooo, equate your equation to zero, and then solve for $t$ just as gekkostate commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You have a quadratic so, if you factor it and you will find the roots or in other words, when the balls hits the ground.

**HINT $2$**

> You can factorize your polynomial by dividing by $-16$ and finding two numbers which add to $-3$ and multiply to $-10$

**HINT $3$**

> Your answer should be in the form $-16(x-a)(x+b)$  where $a$ and $b$ are the numbers which make your equation zero or in other words, the roots.

Comment: I divided it by 16. and got s(t)= -t^2+3t+10. Then I factored it and got (-t-2)(t-5) so the answer is 5 correct?

Comment: You should also take out the negative sign from $s(t)$ and you will get a similar answer: $-16(t+5)(t-2)$

Comment: I understand it now. thank you!

Comment: @gekkostate It should be $-16(t-5)(t+2)$.

Comment: Anytime! I'm not sure if you have visited the help center or seen the FAQ but if you notice, there is a small check mark beside this answer and any other answer you will see on this website. There is also an upvote button and a downvote button. When you have 15 rep, you can upvote and downvote an answer. Also, if you hit the checkmark then the answer will be accepted and will close a "loop" so to speak.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Absolutely! Sorry about that! I can't edit it anymore but that's the correct answer, I messed up the signs.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I also got -16(t-5)(t+2)